# Is there a database containing a list of once common, but now archaic words?

Tags: discussion

Is there a database containing words that were not only once common but also now archaic?

I would like to have a list of, say the 100 statistically most frequently used words in 17th, 18th and 19th Century English but filter out all words still in common use.

So,  for instance, the 'hath' formation would be fairly common in  17th C English,  and would appear on such a list,  but 'the' wouldn't.

Presumably one with coding knowledge could use Google Books/ngram data to generate this?

To clarify: I am aware that there are loads of lists of vocabulary already out there: I want one with some statistical basis.

Comment: Interesting question. I’ve voted to move it to meta.

Comment: Alack, methinks nae.

Comment: You mean other than the OED?

Comment: This [site](https://www.lexico.com/en/explore/archaic-words) gives some archaic words (though I don't know whether this is what you want or not), but no statistical data :(

Comment: Justin: that is a useful list of words,  but let's say you were trying to get a flavour of 17th as opposed to 18th Century English,  how would you be able to say, e.g., "Thou" was very rare in casual 18th Century English? Basically,  has anybody used the extant texts from these periods to generate a distinct lexicon for each period? If not,  could we do it using the data from Google Books,  for example?

Comment: OED is a good source, David M, but can we filter out the rarely used words (calbum, lacuna) from those that are used in lots of different contexts (and that are now archaic to boot)?

Comment: You may get results over on https://stackoverflow.com , since this seems to be in the direction of sources for programming tasks. (they have similar questions there)

Comment: I've downloaded the Google 1-, 2- and 3-grams from [here](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html); actually only the 1-grams are needed to make a list. I'll have a look if it yields something interesting.

Comment: Thanks, Glorfindel. I know it might throw up some odd things due to spelling, but I am surprised no one has done it before as it would be really useful!

Comment: Depends to a great extent on how you define "archaic" (as different from OED). Explore COCA, too. Good Luck.